# Positioning elements next to each other below another element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to position the blue boxes next to each other and below the text "Some random information." How should I approach it?
This is how it looks right now https://imgur.com/a/CEAyfRM

```css
.container2 {
  height: 45vh;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.text5 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  border: 2px solid #3882F6;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="text5">Some random information.

    <div class="box1" id="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2" id="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3" id="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4" id="box4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Flexbox on the ccontainer. Then wrap the text in its own element and let the element span the full width:

```css
.text5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text5 p {
  width: 100%;
}




/* original CSS */
.container2 {
  height: 45vh;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.text5 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  border: 2px solid #3882F6;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="text5">
    <p>Some random information.</p>

    <div class="box1" id="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2" id="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3" id="box3"></div>
    <div class="box4" id="box4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is just on the right side of the text now.

Comment: post the code of your attempt. it is clearly working here